# List comprehension by multiple lists Python 2.7/3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, arraylist, list-comprehension

comunity!

I have program that works well in python 2.7, but when I wanted to perform some visualisation in Jupyter Notebook in Pyhton 3, it reports error:
'map' object is not subscriptable

I've tried some ways to substitute it, but unsuccessfully.

Following list comprehension should concatenate all the items in lists in set order. Hours_list is list of lists, so it should proceed to next list by concatenating the first one, and so on....

Specifically, it concatenates  all numbers from list catVIST (list of one-digit numbers as string), indikat_Taf_num (similar list with format such as ['2', '3', '0'...]) with hours list of format like [['1200', '1300']['1000','1100']].

I should note, that all list are from common source, so the numbers of items are ok. Only problem is that map_object that I just cannot handle yet.

```
code_TAF = [(catVIST[i] + indikat_Taf_num[i] + hours_list[i][j]) for i in range(0,len(catVIST)) for j in range(0,len(hours_list[i]))]
```

\of course, I tried function list(code...), but did not work.

As I said, in pyhton 2.7, it works, not in 3 version.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you do `type(code_TAF)`? And have you tried `code_TAF = list(code_TAF)`?

Comment: I tried `list(code_TAF)` but it, God knows why, does not work.
I have this part included in wider function, so I do not know how to implement `type`.

Comment: `print(type(code_TAF))`? The `type` function is a builtin. Alternatively, use a step-by-step debugger like `pdb` and set a breakpoint there to invstigate the state of things? Or even unpack the `for` loop to make it more clear, and then repack it into a list comprehension once you've figured out what's going on